# How do I get the multiprocessing running?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to get two processes running simultaneously instead of running one at a time. My code is following. Can someone tell me what is wrong? Thanks!

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from os import getpid
from random import randint
from time import time, sleep

def download_task(filename):
    print('Initiate downloading task, task No.[%d].' % getpid())
    print('Begin downloading %s...' % filename)
    time_to_download = randint(5, 10)
    sleep(time_to_download)
    print('Finished downloading %s! It took %d seconds' % (filename, time_to_download))

def main():
    start = time()
    p1 = Process(target=download_task, args=('Python: from beginer to lunatic.pdf',))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=download_task, args=('Peking Hot.avi',))
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    end = time()
    print('It took %.2f seconds in total.' % (end - start))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Right now, this is all I got.

```
It took 0.14 seconds in total.
```

But I am supposed to get something like this:

```
Start downloading Python: from beginer to lunatic.pdf...
Start downloading Peking Hot.avi...
Finished downloading Python: from beginer to lunatic.pdf! It took 5 seconds
Finished downloading Peking Hot.avi! It took 5 seconds
It took 5.00 seconds in total.
```

Comment: It seems to work for me. You might want to add some additional information about the problem you are having

Comment: Oh got it. Sorry it is my first post on Stack Overflow. I am currently using Python 3.8. This code script is from a learning book a while ago, so I am suspecting maybe it has something to do with Python version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should flush the output streams in your multiprocessing bit. You can do this by adding `flush=True` to your print statements, by adding `sys.stdout.flush()` to the end of the function, by adding a single `print("", flush=True)` to the end of the function, or by specifying the `-u` parameter when calling your program from the command line (`python -u your_file_name.py`). The latter runs python in "[unbuffered](https://docs.python.org/3.8/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u)" mode. Any of them should work.